# Javascript file attached via Drupal behaviours does not work occasionally

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm facing a weird issue where a JS file attached via the [Javascript API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) does not work properly. I couldn't really pin down why it isn't working by the JS file consists of a few event listeners which get attached to DOM elements and it looks like this:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.basics = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (context !== document) {
        return;
      }

     initPublicationsAccordion($)
     initBackground($)
     initNavbarFix($)
     initMobileNav($)
     initAuthorsDropdown($)
     setTimeout(() => initCarousel($), 500) // this fixes it
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

and the corresponding `*.libraries.yml` file:

```
global:
  css:
    theme:
      css/main.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - drulma/bulma
    - drulma/mainjs
```

...

```
mainjs:
  js:
    js/main.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
```

There are no errors in the console, but I noticed I can make it work by wrapping the functions in a setTimeout. I would appreciate if anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing your event on document context, which happens only once (basically same as old school `$(document).ready()`). But a major point Drupal behaviors is that they are fired every time when somehing is added to the DOM, even when added with Ajax. (core's  `BigPipe` might add blocks with Ajax, this module is enabled by default)

So instead of the one-shot

```
  Drupal.behaviors.basics = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (context !== document) {
        return;
      }
      ...do stuff
```

target the specific DOM nodes, e.g. if your carousel has a container
`<div class="my_fancy_carousel">...</div>`
attach the behavior to its class:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.my_fancy_carousel  {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.my_fancy_carousel', context).once('init_my_fancy_carousel').each( function() {
        ...do stuff...
```

Also notice the `.once('my_unique_identifier')` part which makes sure your functions don't trigger repeatly on the same DOM node

Comment: If you use `.once()` add `core/jquery.once` to the list of dependencies for your library.

Comment: You guys are legends, it seems like it is working with a quick look. Will confirm.

Comment: Yeah it is working. @Hudri question, do I need to add a new Drupal.behaviours for each event listener I'm attaching or can I wrap this in one? Can you assist me once more with this question?

Comment: You can add everything into a single behavior wrapper, but use different "once's" for different jobs, e.g. use `$('.carousel-selector', context).once('my_carousel')` and a separate `$('a.lightbox', context).once('my_lightbox')`

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful. Is the label in the `once` method used somewhere else, or has some other advantages one can use?